# find the graph in the network where the clicked node belongs to in vispy

Tags: python, numpy, vispy

I'd like code to show, when I click on the node of a graph network it highlights the graph that the node belongs to in vispy

I tried this code but the node doesn't get colored nor the neighbored nodes

```
 def on_mouse_press(event):
        if event.button == 1:

            # Get the node that was clicked on and its index in the
            # graph's list of nodes
            node = event.pos

            # Highlight all edges connected to this node by setting 
            # their widths to 5
            for edge in self.edges:
                if edge[0] == node or edge[1] == node:
                    edge[2].width = 5

            self.canvas.update()

# Connect the callback function to the 'on_mouse_press' 
# event of the graph object
events.on_mouse_press.connect(on_mouse_press)

# Show the canvas with all of its elements
self.canvas.show()
```

Comment: Please include a complete [mre]. 
First remark without it: you can't associate the callback to the event inside the callback. That has to be done somewhere else. Plus, can you provide a link to whatever documentation about that `node_clicked` event? I've never heard of that. And a google search on it provides one single answer: this very question of yours.

Comment: ya I've realised that I have some mistakes, can you please provide me with a startup code on how to highlight the graph that the node belongs to by clicking on the node?

Comment: There is no builtin/easy way in vispy to get a specific point of a MarkersVisual that was clicked on. You can get the entire Visual with `visual_at`, but if you want a particular point out of all the points in the Markers you'll need to probably copy something from the vispy issues as I don't think we have a real example yet. The code in this original issue post seems to have the right idea with the `on_mouse_press` function. https://github.com/vispy/vispy/issues/1618 The idea is to draw each marker again with a unique color and then determine what color the cursor is under.